# Is $V$ a vector space over $R$ under these two operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $V=\{(a,b) : (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Is $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ under:

**Addition**: $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+b_2,a_2+b_1)$

$(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2  \in\mathbb{R})$

**Scalar multiplication**: $t(a,b)=(ta,tb)$

$(t,a,b  \in\mathbb{R})$

There exists an element $0$ so i think it's a vector space.

Am i right?

Comment: $(1,2)+(3,6)=(7,5)$; $(3,6)+(1,2)=(5,7)$.

Comment: i see... thank you.